# Periférico de sonido en inglés?

Tags: definiciones

## English

I was working on a neighbor's computer the other day and, they thought that the speakers weren't working. But, it was actually the "periférico de sonido" that wasn't working. At least that's what the error said. I'm trying to research the problem, but there isn't much about it on the webs in spanish.

---

## Español

Estuve trabajando en una computadora de mis vecinos el otro dia. Ellos pensaron que los audifonos no estaban funcionando. Pero, de hecho era el periférico de sonido. O eso dijo el error. Estoy tratando de investigar esto, pero no hay mucho sobre periféricos de sonido en el internet.

Answer (score 5):

El siguiente vocabulario puede resultar útil:

- speakers = 'altavoces' en España. En algunos países de sudamérica se utiliza el término 'bocina', pero si lo usas en España no te entenderán.
- periférico de sonido  = 'soundcard' (Inglés) o 'tarjeta de sonido' en España. Desconozco el término usado en sudamérica.

Comment: También he visto 'altoparlantes' (como equivalente de 'loudspeakers')

Comment: Nunca lo había oído. No es un término habitual en España.

Answer (score 4):

**English**

Usually when you see the word "periférico" in the context of computers it is referring about an external component for example a printer, a modem, or an external hard drive.

This does not seem to be the case since the phrase "periférico de sonido" would refer to the speakers so my guess is that the error message is referring to the sound card's driver. You can try to find an update on the internet and re install it to see if that solves the issue.

**Español**

Normalmente cuando se usa la palabra "periférico" dentro del contexto de las computadoras se esta hablando de componentes externos como por ejemplo una impresora, un modem o un disco duro externo.

Este no parece ser el caso ya que la frase "periférico de sonido" se referiría a las bocinas por lo que me imagino que el error se refiere al controlador de la tarjeta de sonido. Puedes intentar buscar la actualización en internet y reinstalarlo a ver si eso soluciona el problema.